# How to receive values from server request (s2s)?

Tags: php, mysql, tracking

I'm trying to receive values from s2s (postback) pixel, which means that a server requests my link www.example.com/?cid=XXXX & I want to save cid values to mysql database.
I've tried to run the code on my browser and it work fine, but when used to receive s2s pixel it doesn't.
**I think the problem that I'm using Request, which might be the wrong thing to do when it's server to server.**
What is the difference between your page is called by client, and when its called by a server?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXX";
$dbname = "XXXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// Set values to insert
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem');
$cid= $_REQUEST['cid'];
$Year= date('y');
$Month= date('m');
$Day= date('d');
$Hour= date('G');
$MediumID= substr($cid, 0, 1);
$PublisherID= substr($cid, 1, 2);
$PlacementID= substr($cid, 3, 2);
$CreativeID= substr($cid, 5, 3);
$pos= strpos($cid, "_pid") + 4;
$DynamicID= substr($cid, 8, ($pos-12));

$sql = "INSERT INTO FTDs (Day, Month, Year, Hour, MediumID, PublisherID, PlacementID, CreativeID, DynamicID)
VALUES ('$Day', '$Month', '$Year', '$Hour', '$MediumID', '$PublisherID', '$PlacementID', '$CreativeID', '$DynamicID')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "200";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: How is it `called by a server`? s2s Callback example in PHP https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/monetization/s2s-redeem-callbacks may can help

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping or validating the user input at all. (If someone. for example, sends a `'`-sign in the `$cid` parameter, your query will break.)

Comment: I always recommend that you use `$_GET` an `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`, since the latter can be populated in different ways depending on the server config (php.ini) and might lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: More than 8 bytes of SQL injection will be hard without knowing the code.

Comment: @user3606329 - True, but like I mentioned, it's enough to send in one `'` for the query to break. It's better to do things correctly from the start. With prepared statements, you don't need to care about those things at all.